# Создать хранимую процедуру возвращающую таблицу (Transact-SQL)

Tags: sql-server, sql

Есть таблица, описывающая другие таблицы вида:

```
---------------------------------
| IdTable | NRow | NCol | Value |
---------------------------------
| 001     | 1    |  1   | Наим. |
---------------------------------
| 001     | 1    |  2   | № стр.|
---------------------------------
| 001     | 1    |  3   | Всего |
---------------------------------
| 001     | 2    |  1   |  1    |
---------------------------------
| 001     | 2    |  2   |  2    |
---------------------------------
| 001     | 2    |  3   |  3    |
---------------------------------
| 001     | 3    |  1   | прод1 |
---------------------------------
| 001     | 3    |  2   |  20   |
---------------------------------
| 001     | 3    |  3   |  256  |
---------------------------------
| 002     | ...  |  ... |  ...  |
---------------------------------
| 003     | ...  |  ... |  ...  |
---------------------------------
| 004     | ...  |  ... |  ...  |
---------------------------------
```

Количество столбцов и строк хранится в другой таблице.
Помогите создать запрос, который выводил бы нужную таблицу с учетом столбцов и строк.

Comment: Пока что смотрю в сторону for xml и динамического sql.

Comment: Ну да. Динамическим sql'ем. Генерируешь запрос каждой строки, потом юнион, и так далее. А затем execute.

Answer (score 2):

Вставляем данные:

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#Table')IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #Table
CREATE TABLE #Table(
  IdTable INT,
  NRow INT,
  NCol INT,
  Value NVARCHAR(4000)
)
DECLARE @IdTable INT, @NRow INT, @NCol INT
INSERT #Table VALUES
(1,1,1,'Наим'),
(1,1,2,'№'),
(1,1,3,'Всего'),
(1,2,1,'1'),
(1,2,2,'2'),
(1,2,3,'3'),
(1,3,1,'прод1'),
(1,3,2,'20'),
(1,3,3,'256'),
(2,1,1,'АА'),
(2,1,2,'ББ'),
(2,2,1,'11'),
(2,2,2,'22')
```

Задаём начальные значения(@NRow при этом кстати лишнее):

```
SELECT @IdTable = 1, @NRow = 3, @NCol = 3
```

Генерируем строку вида: [1],[2],[3],[4],[5]... В зависимости от количества столбцов

```
DECLARE
  @SQL NVARCHAR(4000)
;WITH CTE AS(
  SELECT 1 N
  UNION ALL 
  SELECT N+1 
  FROM CTE 
  WHERE N<@NCol
)
SELECT @SQL = STUFF((SELECT CONCAT(',[',N,']') FROM CTE ORDER BY N FOR XML PATH('')),1,1,'')
OPTION(MAXRECURSION 256)
```

Теперь составляем SQL запрос

```
SET @SQL = 
'SELECT ' + @SQL + '
FROM(
   SELECT NRow, NCol, Value
   FROM #Table
   WHERE IdTable = ' + CAST(@IdTable AS VARCHAR(11)) +
')T PIVOT(
   MAX(Value) FOR NCol IN(' + @SQL + ')
)P'

SELECT @SQL
```

Запускаем:

```
EXEC(@SQL)
```

И результаты запросов:

1) вид сгенерированного SQL запроса:

```
SELECT [1],[2],[3]
FROM(
   SELECT NRow, NCol, Value
   FROM #Table
   WHERE IdTable = 1)T PIVOT(
   MAX(Value) FOR NCol IN([1],[2],[3])
)P
```

2) результат выполнения сгенерированного запроса:

```
Наим     №    Всего
1        2    3
прод1    20   256
```

**UPD:**

Кстати, можно высчитать количество столбцов запросом вида:

```
SET @NCol = (SELECT MAX(NCol) FROM #Table WHERE IdTable=@IdTable)
```

тогда скрипт будет более универсальным и чууууууууууууть более медленным.